# Why do I get a missing file/folder error on a deployed Vue.js/Prisma app to Heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, graphql, prisma

I'm working on an app with a prisma and graphql-yoga server, and a Vue.js frontend. The project structure is shown in the linked image. My problem lies on the server side where I'm using ES6. The dev part has been alright, the deploy (to Heroku) smooth. However, I get the Application Error message when I launch the app. A look at the app's heroku logs points toward a broken file/directory path being the culprit, as seen in the linked logs image. Specifically, the generated `prisma.grapqhl` file, which is referenced in the db file.

I'm using babel to compile the server's src content (which includes copying files) before deploying and doing it locally worked just fine. So, what am I doing wrong?

**Project Structure**

[image]

**Error Log**

[image]

**DB file referencing the generated prisma.grapqhl**

[image]